# Distorted graphics on linux screen flashes and heavy tearing

Tags: linux, drivers, intel-graphics, dell-latitude, gnome3

Dell Latitude 7480 using an updated Arch linux - with integrated graphics:

VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] (rev 07)

Few months ago i started experiencing weird graphics interruptions: Gnome DE started flashing and parts of the menus stayed as ghosts after using them.
I moved to i3 where i didn't experience this behavior.

Once in a few minutes i have a weird reddish square artifact. I still try to check out gnome but the issues are still there. In the last couple of weeks i get the following screen and can get out of it only with a hard reset.
[image: my screen when it's going wild]

I tried the TearFree options, the modesetting driver, the Intel driver with config (xf86-video-intel) but without success.

I'm trying to figure out if it's a software or hardware issues.

Will be happy to provide any logs/information that is needed to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it was resolved as hardware issue. There is a problem in the computer's motherboard or memory sticks.

I figured it out with the help of Dell's support team - we ran thorough diagnostics at BIOS level, that ended successfully, but while leaving it on, the distorted screen (as in my question) appeared and we understood it's a proper hardware issue.